# faceting two data sets, two columns with same index on same facet

Tags: r

I have been searching all over for hours and of course found some similar questions, but still I had no success in solving my problem.

Here is my question. I have two data sets same column names, in this example same row names either.

Lets say the data sets are:

```
t <- seq(1, 20, by = 0.5)

num_of_rows <- length(t)

df1 <- data.frame(A = runif(num_of_rows), B = runif(num_of_rows), C = runif(num_of_rows), D = runif(num_of_rows), F = runif(num_of_rows))

dimnames(df1)[[1]] <- t

df2 <- data.frame(A = runif(num_of_rows), B = runif(num_of_rows), C = runif(num_of_rows), D = runif(num_of_rows), F = runif(num_of_rows))

dimnames(df2)[[1]] <- t


df1<-melt(as.matrix(df1))
df2<-melt(as.matrix(df2))
colnames(df1) <- c("X1", "X2", "value")
colnames(df2) <- c("X1", "X2", "value")


ggplot() + geom_line(df1, aes(X1, value, color=factor(X2)), linetype=2) + geom_line(df2, aes(X1, value, color=factor(X2)) + facet_wrap(~X2)
```

What I want is to plot those data sets as facets, each facet with columns with same index from both data sets. I have tied to follow the answers in analog questions i.e. melting, assigning tags for data set number and so on, but I am still receiving ten facets. First five from first data set and next five from second. I would appreciate any help you could provide.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Plot them how? Which plotting function, ggplot2? Show the code you've attempted and we can tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @MrFlick Sorry, I thought, that it was obvious. Yes with ggplot. I have melted both data sets, gave melted dataframes same names, created ggplot() + geom_line(df1, aes(X1, value, color=factor(X2)), linetype=2) + geom_line(df2, aes(X1, value, color=factor(X2)) + facet_wrap(~X2)

Comment: So include that code in your question. No reason to make us do extra work that you've already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want 5 facets, with two lines in each facet differentiated by the source of the data. If so, the idea is to set in your aesthetic `colour=factor(src)` (or however you choose to indicate the source of the data), and then `facet_wrap` by `X2` (as you have done).

```
df1$src <- 1
df2$src <- 2
d <- rbind(df1, df2)

ggplot(d) + 
  geom_line(aes(X1, value, colour=factor(src))) + 
  facet_wrap(~X2, ncol=5)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, seems like exactly what I wanted. I did tag my data sets as data1 and data2 but haven't come up with the idea to set the colour as source of the data. Have you any suggestions, how can I set one line to be dashed ?

Comment: Same idea: set `linetype=factor(src)`.  The documentation for `ggplot` has many useful details and examples.  If you want different line types, see `scale_linetype_manual`.